# CSS problem box-shadow with vertically rendered text

Tags: webkit, css

I have some text rotated 270 degrees, which I would like to apply the `-moz-box-shadow/box-shadow/-webkit-box-shadow` CSS propert to.  Unfortunately, the browsers all render the box shadow as if the text block element has not been rotated (i.e the shadow position is 90 degrees away from where it should be as if in standard left-to-right rendering)

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Can you post your code so we can see what you're doing? (For example one thing you could be doing is setting your transform - rotate on a span element but setting your box-shadow on a container div.)

Here is some webkit code that works:

```
#RRottatte{ -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(270deg);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
top: 300px;
left: 200px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 0px red;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="RRottatte">My Rotated Text</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, your code seems to fail in FF (using the `-moz-transform` and `-moz-box-shadow` equivalents). I need the box to be about 8px padding around the text, and FF only seems to render correctly at larger widths/heights (and even then it behaves unusually).  Webkit based browsers work as expected

Comment: I think box-shadow is a pretty new addition to firefox, so would expect some shake-out. Will try out the ff extensions and see what I find.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably applying the box shadow to a parent container (which is not rotated), you must apply it to the container which has the transform, i.e:

http://jsfiddle.net/QK9wG/

Comment: There is a possible bug with FF (3.6), if you apply the `-moz-transform` and `-moz-text-shadow` equivalents to the JSFiddle you have created, you can see that the shadow is only applied to the bottom half of the transformed element.

Comment: Note this only seems to happen when the element is rotated through 90 or 270 degrees (with the negative equivalents)